# How can I invoke 'Vacuum the Kitchen' in google smart home?

Tags: google-smart-home

What traits should I use if I want a Vacuum cleaner to clean specific room? 
I've tried using `Modes` trait with `action.devices.types.VACUUM`, e.g.:

```
"attributes": {
  "availableModes": [
    {
      "name": "room",
      "name_values": [
        {
          "name_synonym": [
            "room"
          ],
          "lang": "en"
        }
      ],
      "settings": [
        {
          "setting_name": "kitchen",
          "setting_values": [
            {
              "setting_synonym": [
                "Kitchen"
              ],
              "lang": "en"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "setting_name": "livingroom",
          "setting_values": [
            {
              "setting_synonym": [
                "Living room"
              ],
              "lang": "en"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ordered": false
    }
  ]
```

But `vacuum the kitchen` responds with `Sorry, it looks like that device hasn't been set up yet` though `set vacuum room to kitchen` works. End user can use routines to accomplish this, but is it doable by simply using traits? `Modes` or perhaps `Toggle` ?

Answer (score 0):

uh, overlooked `availableZones` on the `StartStop` trait. Working fine

```
"attributes": {
  "pausable": false,
  "availableZones": [
    "kitchen",
    "livin groom",
    "bedroom",
    "table"
  ]
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/440